# JavaScript input reset value not work in onblur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, input

I have this function:

```
inputT1.onblur = function () {
    var pDomain = this.value;

    $.get("netutil/php/trial500.php", {
        P1: 'dominio',
        P2: pDomain
    }, function (data, status, xhr) {
        var respDom = JSON.parse(data);
        if (parseInt(respDom.isreal) === 1) {
            inputT1.value = '';
        }
    });
}
```

But `inputT1.value` isn't being blanked.
How can I clean input element `inputT1` in my function?

Thanks in advance,

AM

Comment: So maybe the success callback isn't called or the condition deosn't reached. Check your console/network tab. You have to debug it...

Comment: Yes it's called, i have inserted an alert into if condition and it was show.

Comment: Try with specifying the radix, `parseInt(value, 10)`.

Comment: Can you reproduce it online? Which browser are you using?

Comment: What does `typeof data` return? Are you sure jQuery doesn't parse the JSON for you? Use the third argument of the `$.get` method: `$.get('url', fn, 'json')` and remove the `JSON.parse` line.

Answer (score 0):

If `inputT1` is a jquery object, you need to call the `.val()` method rather than trying to set value:

```
inputT1.val('');
```

This should reset the value.

EDIT:

Not on right track, but keeping to save comments until answered.

Comment: OP uses `onblur` so `inputT1` doesn't seem be a jQuery object.

Comment: @almal It would be helpful if you providing the html and the code you're using to grab the element.

Comment: Hi, no html just DOM, I create the element dynamically so var inputT1 = document.createElement('input');
 inputT1.type = "text";
 inputT1.id = 'inputT1';

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's entering the if statement in your callback?